# How can I create connection pool to back processed browsers on sidekiq start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In my project I got initializer for pool of selenium browsers.

```
/config/initializers/browser_init.rb
```

it looks like this:

```
BrowserProvider.init_pool
```

`init_pool` is just a method which create pool and push browsers to that.
I use Sidekiq for back proccessing in that browsers. So my problem is: every time when I start rails server and Sidekiq that initialize 2 different pools(1 for rails server, 1 for sidekiq). And I don't need pool for rails server. I've tried to init pool in Sidekiq initializer, but it did not help. Is any way I can init that pool only when Sidekiq start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
BrowserProvider.init_pool if Sidekiq.server?
```